# Can't remove event listener - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've something similar to the following code.

```
'use strict'

let Cache = {}

function Preloader(asset) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    Cache[asset] = img;
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event(`${asset}_preloaded`));
  }
  img.src = asset;
}

class Sprite {
  constructor(params) {
    this._src = params.src;
    if(Cache[this._src]) {
      this.init();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener(`${this._src}_preloaded`, () => this.init(), false);
      Preloader(this._src);
    }
  }

  init() {
    window.removeEventListener(`${this._src}_preloaded`, () => this.init(), false);
    this._width = Cache[this._src].width;
    this._height = Cache[this._src].height;
  }
}
```

When a new Sprite is created with an image as a parameter, it checks if the image is alredy cached. If it's not it calls the Preloader to load it. Events are used so the Preloader can tell the Sprite when the image has been loaded into the cache.

The event is added and dispatched correctly, also the `init` function is called correctly, but the event isn't removed.

Comment: I have a question here. Why are you create distinct events for all the images? You could have a single event that stays on window or Document for that matter and have it trigger whenever any image loads and pass the image src as data to the event

Comment: @AndrewL there are no type annotations, so this looks like normal JS using ES6 classes and block scope.

Comment: @AndrewL this is es6.

Comment: you are passing 2 separate functions - just pass `this.init`.

Comment: @DanielA.White: That's the problem, yeah, but passing `this.init` would lose `this` during the call; `init` isn't an arrow function or a bound function.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not passing two functions. I'm passing one function which then calls another function. I'm using an arrow function there to preserve `this`

Comment: Based on @T.J.Crowder comment I've solved the problem by moving the `init` fuction into the constructor as an arrow function. Thank you!

Comment: @Hidden: Glad that helped. What Daniel meant was you're passing two separate functions to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` (that is, one each, but not the *same* one, which is why it won't work -- has to be the same function).